# In Mongoose, how to filter an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var sampleSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  dates: [{
    date: Date,
    duration: Number
  }]
});
```

I'd need to filters the records according to the following rule: if one of dates is later than a given date date_begin, keep the record, otherwise, don't.

I have the impression that $gte or $lte are the function I need, but I can't find a way to use them correctly. I tried

```
sampleSchema.find({date_begin: {$gte: 'date'}});
```

or some variants of that, but I can't seem to be able to make it work. Anyone has an idea of how I am supposed to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To do querying on elements inside arrays, [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) is used :

```
SampleModel.find( { dates : { $elemMatch: {  date : { $gte: 'DATE_VALUE' } } } } )
```

If you're using a [single query condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition), you can directly filter:

```
SampleModel.find( { 'dates.date': { $gte: 'DATE_VALUE' } } )
```